# can IntelliJ recognize a directory of html and php files as a single project?

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I have a website using HTML, CSS, and PHP. I'm starting to use intelliJ's community addition, and it works great for the most part, but it's unable to recognize functions from included files.

I tried to open my website as a project but it wouldn't let me. Anyone know if it's possible to have IntelliJ read all my files in a directory and tie things together?

Comment: Community Edition has only basic syntax highlighting support. For the full JavaScript/PHP support you need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate or PhpStorm. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Comment: thanks! appreciate the reply